# Writing active storage output to tempfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

How do you write the output of the activestorage download to a tempfile.

Whenever I read it out afterwards, it just becomes an empty string.

This is the code I've tried:

```
@file_temp = Tempfile.new
@file_temp.binmode
@file_temp.write(model.activestorage_attribute.download)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also just call [`ActiveStorage::Blob#open`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-open) instead of reinventing the wheel.

> Downloads the blob to a tempfile on disk. Yields the tempfile.

```
blob.open do |temp_file|
  # do something with file...
end
# file is automatically closed and unlinked
```

If you really want to do it yourself then the right way to do it is:

```
# Using `Tempfile.open with a block ensures that
# the file is closed and unlinked
Tempfile.open do |tempfile| 
  tempfile.binmode
  # steams the file as chunks instead of loading it 
  # all into memory
  model.activestorage_attribute.download do |chunk|
    tempfile.write(chunk)
  end
  tempfile.rewind
  # do something with tempfile
end
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. If someone is interested in looking at the proper source code of how Rails does it, check https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activestorage/lib/active_storage/downloader.rb - notice the creation of the tempfile, the download using chunks (so it won't load the entire file in memory, only one chunk at a time and writing to disk) and finally the `ensure` block, where `file.close!` is called (the bang `close!` closes the file and unlinks it, which means immediate deletion from the disk).

Answer (score 4):

The `ActiveStorage::Blob#download` will provide you with a blob that can be used to different operations from memory.

The `Tempfile.new` will create files which are IO objects and have a position pointer. When you write to a file, the position will advance.

You need to `rewind` to the position. Try the following:

```
@file_temp = Tempfile.new
@file_temp.binmode
@file_temp.write(model.activestorage_attribute.download)
@file_temp.rewind
```

Then you'll be able to read the data:

```
@file_temp.read
#=> "...\x8F\xFF\x00\x16G\xFE\xAE\x0F\xE5\x0E\xED..."
```

Comment: A better way to do this that avoids reading the whole file into memory would be to do `model.activestorage_attribute.download {|chunk| @file_temp.write(chunk) }`.